# Connection issue after some idle time with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, .net-4.5, stackexchange.redis

I'm experiencing an issue with StackExchange.Redis: after some idle time (some hours), the whole provider is unable to connect to Redis again throwing the so-called exception `It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer [...]`.

Everything goes fine again if I recycle the IIS application pool, and after another idle time, the issue happens again. This is why I guess it's not a problem with the Redis instance but with StackExchange.Redis, because I'm not restarting the Redis service but the IIS application pool.

Is there any guidance on how to manage the Redis multiplexer in addition to ensuring that there's a single multiplexer instance per application domain?

Comment: @MarcGravell It seems like you're dead :D

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/42) for some possible workarounds. It's still an open issue though.

Comment: @TwBert I see! It seems like it's something with DNS. I will try to do the connect against 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and see what happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I've solved this setting `AbortOnConnectFail` to `false`. This seems to fix the issue for now.